# How to hide a field of the editor by default

Tags: editor

I am working on a blog with a pretty high number of authors. I want to keep them from accidentally sending a push message to our readers, since the button of the push-plugin we use looks dangerously similar to the "publish"-button.

Is there a way to hide an element like this push-button for certain user groups by default?

I can uncheck it in the view-menu above the editor, of course, but that doesn't change it for all other authors.

Comment: Hide the content editor?

Comment: Our authors need the content editor to publish their posts. Additionally, they unfortunately have to be able to edit their posts later on. So hiding the whole editor is no option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple options.

You could just create a stylesheet that loads in the admin area, and enable that for certain users if needed.  Here is an example of loading a stylesheet in the admin for users with the role of "shopmanager".

```
function my_admin_styles(){
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if( ! empty($user) && count(array_intersect(["shop_manager"], (array) $user->roles ))) {
        wp_enqueue_style(
            'admin_css', 
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/admin-shopmanager.css', array(), filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/css/admin-shopmanager.css') 
        );
    }
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_styles');
```

Then in your stylesheet add something like this...

```
#elementID {
    display: none !important;
}
```

You might also try a plugin called "[Capability Manager Enhanced](https://wordpress.org/plugins/capability-manager-enhanced/)" which allows you to disable things based on user role.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It's more of a workaround because it utilizes a plugin but does what I've been looking for. I use the plugin Adminimize to hide the ID of the concerned field (which you can find out using Chromes or Firefox' inspector tools) for the usergroup 'Author'.